Creating an asset procedurally
I am developing an IoT device that monitors a proprietary bus that may have one- or more bus participants (but usually more than one). I want to create a Thingsboard Device for my IoT gateway (to monitor health), and an additional Thingsboard Device for each bus participant found on the bus, all of them correlated under a Thingsboard Asset.
My first question is: is this setup considered best practice for this problem? Is there a better architecture?
My second question is: how can I do this procedurally? It is trivial to auto-provision a device, but there seems to be no way to create an asset (only via REST API).
My current best idea is this:

IoT device provisions a Thingsboard Device for itself (already doing this)
it makes an RPC call to create an Asset
Asset is created from rule chain by making a REST API call and relation is set to the Device that was just created (credentials are always on the server, never gets sent to the device)
a Thingsboard Device is created for each discovered bus participant, and is added to the Asset (either by the device or from Rule Chain, not yet sure)

What do you all think?
Single device provisioning works. I've been trying to find a community where one can brainstorm architectural questions like this.
